# Repopulate UITableView with New Data

Tags: sql, xcode, uitableview

I am implementing a search functionality using UIAlertView that will search a SQL Table for a match and repopulate the UITableView. So far I have this code below. "results" is array of match returned data from the search query. Then, I checked if the "elements" are empty which means it does not match any item in SQL Table. If it does then I would like to erase the data currently on UITableView and replace with the "results" data.

Here is my code so far:

```
            NSUInteger *elements = [results count];
            if(elements == 0)
            {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Item Not Found" message:@"Sorry the item was not found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [av show];
            }
            if(elements >= 1)
            {
                    //Repopulate UITableView with Data
                    self.itemTitles = itemstitle;
                    self.itemPrices = itemsprice;
                    self.itemCategory = itemscategory;
            }
```

Note: I tried to use `[tableView reloadData]` but not sure how to implement it in this case.

Thanks in advance for the help.